# Why did a nine-day-old answer pop up in the new user first answer review queue?

Tags: bug

here - https://english.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/269683

(lets do the time warp again)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the Stack Exchange garbage-collection daemon — who’s affectionately nicknamed *the Roomba* — has just had its way with [this closed question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/423926/2085).

That delete not just the question but an answer from the again-new user, since it brought the owner of the post in your review down below some new-user threshold, which kicked one of their remaining posts into the FP queue.